# How to add thread to Winform for button-check

Tags: c#, multithreading, button

in C# i have simple Winform with currently one button "start" that executes a funcion in the click-event. This function takes about 20seconds.
Now i added a second button "stop" that sets a variable "buttonstopclicked = 1" in the click-event.
In the function of the start-button i check for this variable and quit the function if it is set to 1.

The problem is: I cannot click the stop-button while c# is executing the event of the start-button.

Question is now: How can i add a thread for everything to handle the buttons?

Thanks for help

Edit:
Meanwhile i found out how to create the thread:

```
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ButtonThread));
    myThread.Start();

    private void ButtonThread()
    {
        while (1 != 0)
        {
            if (ButtonStartClicked == 1)
            {
                ButtonStartClicked = 0;
                ExecuteFunction();
            }

            if (ButtonStopClicked == 1)
            {
                ButtonStopClicked = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

But now i get an exception in the called function "ExecuteFunction".
        InvalidOperationException.

Something that the control was used/created from another thread...

What can i do here now?
I am using C# 2010 express

Comment: the start method needs to be handled by a thread to let your gui response as normal. this could be done with a backgroundworker http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What version of .Net/Visual studio are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual C# 2010 express.

Comment: This is an example of very inefficient programming. When you ask a question, do read the comments posted by fellow members. Read a bit about Background-worker, it's not rocket science. It will take just few minutes and you won't be messing up your code like this.

Answer (score 2):

The buttons run on the UI thread and you are trying to interact with the UI thread using a custom thread. For responsiveness in the UI, you need to use background worker. Create a background worker and add your function to be executed in its Do_Work event. Set the following properties to be true (where bw is the name of backgroundworker) :

```
bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
```

Now, on the start button you just need to invoke the background worker, by adding this code in the click event of the start button:

```
If Not bw.IsBusy = True Then
    bw.RunWorkerAsync()
End If
```

And to cancel the process, you need to add the following code in the click event of the stop button:

```
If bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True Then
    bw.CancelAsync()
End If
```

Go through the following msdn link for details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 2):

First of all. Using Thread is not really the best way to go. There are higher level abstraction to that available in the .Net Framework. You should (nearly) always use the highest abstraction a language provides and leave the internals to the Compiler or the Runtime because they will do a great job.

Using VS 2010, you at least have access to the TPL (Task Parallel Library - [Introduction](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx))

For cancellation of a Task (which under the hood makes use of a Thread offered by the ThreadPool) you should use a [CancellationTokenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private CancellationTokenSource _ctSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

The handler for the cancel button then simply sets the cancellation token:

```
private void OnButtonCancelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _ctSource.Cancel();
}
```

The handler for the start button could look like that:

```
private void OnButtonStartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Start a new task
    Task<int> workerTask = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(
        () => PerformLongRunningOperation(_ctSource.Token), _ctSource.Token);

    // when the task has finished, display the result (On the GUI Thread!)
    workerTask.ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Calculation has been canceled.");
            return;
        }

        _LabelResult = task.Result;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext); // required to run this part on the GUI thread
}
```

Where the method that performs the actual work would look something like this:

```
private int PerformLongRunningOperation(CancellationToken token)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        // will cancel the task if the token has been set
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        // otherwise do some stuff
    }

    return 42;
}
```

If you would have access to VS2012 and .NetFramework 4.5 / C# 5.0, using async - await,  the button click handler can even be reduced to something like this:

```
private async void OnButtonStartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Await will allow the UI to keep responsive
        // Furthermore it will automatically return to the UI SynchronizationContext when done, so updating a label
        // has not to be dispatched.
        _LabelResult = await Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => PerformLongRunningOperation(_ctSource.Token), _ctSource.Token);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Calculation has been canceled.");
    }
}
```

For general introduction to Parallel programming with C# visit http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Parallel_Programming

Please keep in mind, that asynchrony leads to a lot of other issues you have to think about. For example, when your UI is responsive (what it should be) the user has the possibility to hit the start button again and again. So in your scenario for example you should think about disabling the button until the task has finished or was canceled in order to avoid that.